# Building with Maven on travis-ci: javadoc plugin won't fail

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml, travis-ci

I'm trying out Travis-CI to build a recently-released Open source Java project. This is my .travis.yml file:

```
language: java
script: mvn clean install -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=false
```

I tried that last flag because I read in the docs that that flag defaults to true, and I do see it in the build logs on travis-ci:

```
$ mvn install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B -V
```

However, when the next line in the log is run, the build succeeds:

```
$ mvn clean install -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=false

...

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I know this is incorrect because the build fails on my personal machine (on a javadoc build error), running maven 3.2.5, and the build also fails when building it on a bamboo server with the same arguments, even with just `mvn clean install`:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.9.1:jar (attach-javadocs) on project luces: MavenReportException: Error while creating archive:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - <filepath>: error: tag not allowed here: <li>
[ERROR] * <li>0 for int / long</li>
[ERROR] ^
```

here's the relevant part of the Pom that's using the javadoc plugin:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

I checked and Travis-CI says they're using [Maven 3.2.x](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Maven-version) as well. Is this a bug in Travis-CI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. The issue was I was running JDK8 on the environments where it was failing, and travis-ci was running on JDK7 by default. Setting the jdk to oraclejdk8 on travis-ci caused the same failure, as expected.